# How to restart app when source code modified in pyramid python framework?

Tags: python, pyramid, autoload, restart

Is there any way to restart app when code file modified in pyramid framework?

```
pyramid.reload_templates
```

this varialbe work for template, but not for source code.
I want to restart project asas code modified as nodemon npm package.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Pyramid documentation on [Reloading Code](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/project.html#reloading-code) (pruned for relevance):

> During development, it's often useful to run `pserve` using its `--reload` option. When `--reload` is passed to `pserve`, changes to any Python module your project uses will cause the server to restart. This typically makes development easier, as changes to Python code made within a Pyramid application is not put into effect until the server restarts.

```
$VENV/bin/pserve development.ini --reload
```

> Changes to template files (such as `.pt` or `.mak` files) won't cause the server to restart. Changes to template files don't require a server restart as long as the `pyramid.reload_templates` setting in the `development.ini` file is true. Changes made to template files when this setting is true will take effect immediately without a server restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your project to restart when code changes then you probably need to wrap it in a reload function that watches your files and reloads your server.

See [here](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/kriswiniarski/jebEbn) for an example snippet. This has been originally taken from CherryPy project.